# How to set elements html content from a string using JS?

Tags: javascript

Before:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

After:

```
<div id="foo"><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">best site eva</a></div>
```

How to accomplish this with pure JS (no jQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways, probably the simplest is

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">best site eva</a>';
```